# MySQL statment, how to show when a column has not results

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this two tables

```
   TABLE_A                       TABLE_B
id_user|name            id_user | points | date
-------------           ------------------------
    1  | A                 1    |   10   |  yesterday
    2  | B                 2    |   10   |  today
    3  | C                 2    |   20   |  today
                           3    |   15   |  today
```

Well, i need to show how many points will earn EVERY user "today", i need to show it although he doesn't earn any amount of points, something like:

```
      VIEW_POINTS
name | sum(points)_today
------------------------
  1  |   0
  2  |   30
  3  |   15
```

I tried differents sentences, but i can't show user 1 when he doesn't earn any points, it just shows the other users that have some points.

Comment: Yes, table_b shows how many points they won during the month, i have to show EVERY user and the amount of points they won at some day of the month, but some days some users doesn't earned any point

Comment: What SQL statements have you tried using so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.id_user, t1.name, COALESCE(SUM(t2.points), 0) AS points
FROM TABLE_A AS t1 
LEFT JOIN TABLE_B AS t2 ON t1.id_user = t2.id_user AND t2.date = 'today'
GROUP BY t1.id_user, t1.name
```

The crucial part of the `LEFT JOIN` is the fact that it's `ON` clause also contains the `t2.date = 'today'` predicate: this way *all* `TABLE_A` rows are selected, even the ones that have not a today's date.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/597fc/2)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use left join:

```
SELECT a.id_user AS name, SUM(COALESCE(b.points, 0)) AS `sum(points)_today`
FROM TABLE_A a LEFT JOIN TABLE_B b
    ON a.id_user = b.id_user AND b.date = 'today'
GROUP BY a.id_user
```

Comment: i would say `GROUP BY a.id_user`. name has chance of being duplicate

Comment: If you add `b.date = 'today' ` in where clause then the users who don't earn any point today will be missed out.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can To show 0 (for the value column) if there is no result, use 
"IFNULL"
 select t1.user_id,  IFNULL(t2.points, 0) like this.

[IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)